# Render Textures at same position with one as partial mask

Tags: opengl

With OpenGL, is there any way to render two textures at the same position and blend them together with alpha blending so that one appears on top of the other? I am trying to make it so that my back-texture can be dynamic on the secondary texture will have a 'window' that will show the texture 'behind' it. I have done quite a bit of research and have tried several combinations of glDepthFunc, glBlendFunc, etc. and have not found any combination that works. I am guessing that this is possible, but just haven't found the trick.

Answer (score 0):

its been awhile, but ill try to help some?

first you have to have GL_BLEND enabled

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

and then i usually have to follow that with a

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

But i usually use delphi so not sure how closely this will help you..

Comment: That's pretty much the same use as in what I'm using (Java), but I still end up with z-fights when trying that one.

Comment: um not sure what you mean by zfights,  but the farther one should have a less alpha then the front one.  and less diffusion alpha.. Sorry not more help :/

Comment: Spatially, there is no back and front. (there is one rendered first and one second, but they are occupying the same space.) I am sure (in fact I know) that the method you have given works when they aren't in the same space, but...

Comment: Ahh , so the objects are exactly the same x,y,z  and you what the two colors to blend...like one color is red , one is blue . you expect to see a purpleish color..?

Comment: Sort of, but only when transparent. So, if A is blue and B is red, red will be the only color, unless B is transparent, then it alpha blends.